# How to check if items of XML string already exist in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, select, insert

I have a longer stored procedure with one of the input parameters being an xml string that contains keywords / tags (formatted as `xml`, using SQL Server 2008). I need to check for each of these tags whether they already exist in a table and if not, insert them there.

So far I have the following lines but my problem is how to write the Where clause here (`@tag` is just a placeholder for demonstration). How do I have to change this?

**My SQL (only relevant part):**

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT      * 
    FROM        RC_Tags 
    WHERE       tag = @tag
)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO RC_Tags
        (
                tag
        )
        SELECT  ParamValues.tag.value('.', 'varchar(255)')
        FROM    @xmlTags.nodes('/tags/tag') AS ParamValues(tag)

    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use [**NOT EXISTS**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx) and use it in your query like this -

```
INSERT INTO RC_Tags
(
        tag
)
SELECT ParamValues.tag.value('.', 'varchar(255)')
FROM @xmlTags.nodes('/tags/tag') AS ParamValues(tag)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT tag
        FROM RC_Tags
        WHERE tag = ParamValues.tag.value('.', 'varchar(255)')
        )
```

and no need to add if condition.

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot - will accept as soon as I can. :)